# Vector char strange chars

Tags: c, char, printf, strcpy

Anyone know how to copy to strings? Cause I used the function strcpy but when I print the result it show strange characters. I want to concatenate 'name' + '@' + 'e-mail'. With scanf I have to put the character null '\0'?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (){

    char message[150];
    char name[150];
    char mail[150];
    char result[150];
    printf("Introduce name: \n");
    scanf("%s",message);
    printf("Introduce email \n");
    scanf("%s",server);
    strcpy(result,message);
    result[strlen(result)]='@'; 
    strcpy(&result[strlen(result)],server);
    printf("RESULT: %s\n",result);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `result[strlen(result)]='@';` will delete the 0-terminator of the string. Did you try `strcat`?

Comment: It also depends on what `server` is and whether you are overflowing the buffer `result`.

Comment: `snprintf(result, sizeof result, "%s@%s", message, server);`, also `char mail[150];` --> `char server[150];`

Answer (score 4):

`result[strlen(result)]='@';` overwrites the NUL terminator introduced into `result` by `strcpy(result,message);`. So the result of a subsequent `strlen` is undefined.

A better solution is to use `strncat`, or you could get away with writing

`char result[150] = {'\0'};`

which will initialise the entire array.

But you still run the risk of overflowing your `result` array. You could use the safer `strncpy` to obviate that. Better still, use `snprintf` and have the C standard library perform the concatenation for you.

Comment: Yes, definitely use `snprintf(result, sizeof result, "%s@%s", message, server);`. Also consider better names for the variables, they don't match the prompts very well.